# How to Login Using Gmail account in Android

Tags: android, authentication, gmail

Google Authentication can verify my account if my account is added in my device.

But I want to login from my application login form where user will give his gmail account Id and password. I will test whether the gmail account is valid or not what the user has entered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must follow any of this tutorial.This example is quite impressive and will guide you to login in your app using gmail account.

- [Google Account integration in android](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/google-account-integration-in-android-login-with-gmail.html)

If you still have any problem in implementation.Comment here.Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
**Dependency**
    **Need Internet Permission** 

**Working Code   see Link on  play Store**
https://play.google.com/store/search?q=com.codecube.airbucks

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Logout"
            android:id="@+id/btn"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    package com.keshav.geofencing;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
    import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
    import com.facebook.FacebookException;
    import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
    import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
    import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
    import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
    import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
    import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.OptionalPendingResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;

    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.util.Arrays;

    import utilities.CommonMethod;
    import utilities.LoginPreferences;


    public class LoginWithGmail extends AppCompatActivity
            implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

        private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
        private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
        private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
        Button loginSub;
        LinearLayout signInButton;


        String gmailId;
        String gmailName;
        String gmailUserEmailId;
        Uri gmailUserPhoto;
        String savePassword;
        LinearLayout btnlogin;
        TextView btnsigning;
        ProgressDialog prgDialog;

        private CallbackManager callbackManager;

        private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;
        private LinearLayout fbloginButton;
    //    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
        private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

        EditText edtEmail;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login1);

            checkPermission();

            GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .addApi(AppIndex.API).build();


            // Google Sign up Button
            signInButton = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

            signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(LoginWithGmail.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
                        if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            //showing dialog to select image

                            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                            signInIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
                            Log.e("permission", "granted");
                        } else {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginWithGmail.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                        signInIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
                    }

                }
            });

        }

        public void checkPermission() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(LoginWithGmail.this,
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

                if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //showing dialog to select image
                    if (CommonMethod.isNetworkAvailable(LoginWithGmail.this)) {
                        Log.e("keshav", "Permission if part marsh");
                    } else {
                        CommonMethod.showAlert("Internet Connectivity Failure", LoginWithGmail.this);
                    }

                    Log.e("keshav", "permission granted");
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginWithGmail.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
    //        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
    //                new IntentFilter(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
            super.onPause();
        }


        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
                handleSignInResult(result);
            }
        }

        // TODO ADD ME

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (opr.isDone()) {
                // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
                // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
                Log.e(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
                GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
                handleSignInResult(result);
            } else {
                // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
                // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
                // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
                showProgressDialog();
                opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        // [START signOut]
        private void signOut() {
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status status) {
                            // [START_EXCLUDE]
    //                        updateUI(false);
                            // [END_EXCLUDE]
                        }
                    });
        }
        // [END signOut]

        // [START revokeAccess]
        private void revokeAccess() {
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status status) {
                            // [START_EXCLUDE]
    //                        updateUI(false);
                            // [END_EXCLUDE]
                        }
                    });
        }
        // [END revokeAccess]

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
            // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
            // be available.
            Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
        }

        private void showProgressDialog() {
            if (mProgressDialog == null) {
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            }
            if (LoginWithGmail.this != null && mProgressDialog != null && !mProgressDialog.equals("null"))
                mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        private void hideProgressDialog() {
            if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()&& !mProgressDialog.equals("null")) {
                mProgressDialog.hide();
            }
        }


        // TODO ADD ME ENd


        private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
            Log.e("&&&s", "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
                GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

                gmailId = acct.getId();
                gmailName = acct.getDisplayName();
                gmailUserEmailId = acct.getEmail();
                gmailUserPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();

                Log.e("gmailId", "is -->" + gmailId);
                Log.e("gmailName", "is -->" + gmailName);
                Log.e("gmailUserEmailId", "is -->" + gmailUserEmailId);
                Log.e("gmailUserPhoto", "is -->" + gmailUserPhoto);

                LoginPreferences.getActiveInstance(LoginWithGmail.this).setUserName(gmailName);
                LoginPreferences.getActiveInstance(LoginWithGmail.this).setProfileImage(""+gmailUserPhoto);


                Log.e("information", "using Gmail is > " + gmailId + " " + gmailName + "" + gmailUserEmailId + "" + gmailUserPhoto);

                if (CommonMethod.isNetworkAvailable(LoginWithGmail.this)) {
                    Log.e("SignUp gmail", "Hit API..........................");
                    Intent i=new Intent(LoginWithGmail.this,DrawerActivity.class);
                    LoginPreferences.getActiveInstance(LoginWithGmail.this).setIsLoggedIn(true);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();

                    // TODO Here Registered User in own Database call Volley Retrofit2 Api ....
                    new SignUpSocialFacebookAsyncTask().execute();
                } else {
                    CommonMethod.showAlert("Intenet Connectivity Failure", LoginWithGmail.this);
                }

            } else {

            }
            // TODO ADD ME KESHAV Google GMail Logout
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();

            // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
            // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
            Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                    Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                    "Login Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                    // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                    // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                    // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                    Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                    // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                    Uri.parse("android-app://com.keshav.geofencing/http/host/path")
            );
            AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(mGoogleApiClient, viewAction);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }

        //Todo  add new method for permission
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
            if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                signInIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

            }
        }

    }

    **Dependency**
    **Need Internet Permission** 

**Working Code   see Link on  play Store**
https://play.google.com/store/search?q=com.codecube.airbucks

Please Like this post if it is helpful
```